# Run tests through multiple environments and browsers with Nunit FrameWork

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm new to using the Nunit Framework so I've been trying to research how to do this.

Basically, I have 3 environments: Dev, Test, Prod
Each environment has a different URL such as:

- Dev: www.dev.com
- Test: www.test.com
- Prod: www.prod.com

I want to run the test cases against all three environments as well as run them through a browser loop for Chrome, FireFox, IE, and Edge.

I have the current code laid out like this to run all tests through each browser:

```
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(EdgeDriver))]

class IntegrationTests
{
    Test.RunAll();
}

[TestFixture(typeof(ChromeDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(InternetExplorerDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(FirefoxDriver))]
[TestFixture(typeof(EdgeDriver))]

class SmokeTests
{
    Test.RunAll();
}
```

From my understanding, you may(?) be able to overload the TestFixtures again but I can't seem to find anything on the syntax of that. I also can't seem to find an instance where someone is using multiple URL's AND browser loops. Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Three different URLs times four browsers makes twelve different fixture instances. You can do that by specifying `TestFixtureAttribute` twelve times instead of four, with entries like...

`C#
[TestFixture(typeof(ChromDriver), "www.dev.com")]`

More likely, however, you will want a given test run to focus on either the dev, test or prod environment.

In that case, pass the URL as a parameter to the run. In the console runner, you would do this with an option like `--params:siteurl=www.dev.com`. Your test would access the value using `TestContext.Parameters`.